# Slow Save in Entity Framework, very specific entity

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a very interesting (and confusing) issue for quite a while, but cannot get to the bottom of it

I have a `WPF` Project built on `Entity Framework`, with about 100 different entities/tables, which all work smoothly. except for one entity type, named SaleProduct

Saving a SaleProduct takes about 5 minutes, sometimes even more (other entities take under 2 seconds usually). And only in the window.

For testing purposes, I put this code in app startup:

```
  Using d = GetSystemContext(True)
        Dim sp = d.Find(Of SaleProduct)(66246)
        sp.DiscountAmount += 1
        d.SaveChanges()
  End Using
```

And saving there is OK(11 seconds, bearable).

But when I open a window with the SaleProduct as the `DataContext` and save there, it takes several minutes.

So, I would like to debug this. Maybe I have some bad code somewhere. But I'm not managing with this either. If I press pause in `Visual Studio` while the app is stuck saving, it freezes on the `SaveChanges` line, meaning not some custom code. So what difference should it make if we are in the app startup or in the window?

But lets take this a step further, I disabled `Just My Code` to get a better picture of whats freezing. And it gets stuck here:

InternalDispatcher.cs

```
try
  {
     interceptionContext.MutableData.SetExecuted(operation(target, interceptionContext));
  }
```

Where the target is a pretty simple `SQL` statement

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Sales]
SET [LastEditedOn] = @0
WHERE ([ID] = @1)
SELECT [AutoPurchaseDate], [GrantingDate], [ReceivedOn], [Name], [TotalVatRate]
FROM [dbo].[Sales]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ID] = @1
```

Running this in `SSMS` takes <1 seconds.

But looking at the complete call stack I see that actually its stuck someplace in `System.Data.dll`. Though try as I might I cant find its `.pdb`.

So I tried to use decompile, but I get an error

> Unable to compile the module

Even though, in the modules window the status is "Symbols loaded".

So I cannot pinpoint precisely.

For kicks, I tried upgrading to .net 4.8 (from 4.7). same problem.

What can I do? How to proceed? Where more can I Investigate?

NOTES

1. Tables Sales and SaleProducts both have `Clustered` `Primary Keys`.
2. Running `SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE open_tran = 1` in `SSMS` while the code is stuck, returns 0 rows.
3. In`SaveChanges`, `ChangeTracker.Entries` returns precisely 2 entities. The SaleProduct, and its parent Sale.

I've posted a Profiler Trace here https://pastebin.com/enLgE0Ln

Here's the full StackTrace if it might help someone

```
[Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Data.dll!SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSyncOverAsync(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle pConn, ref System.IntPtr packet, int timeout) Unknown
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()   Unknown
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()   Unknown
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()   Unknown
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(out byte value)  Unknown
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior runBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmdHandler, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dataStream, System.Data.SqlClient.BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject stateObj, out bool dataReady)  Unknown
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    Unknown
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.MetaData.get()  Unknown
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader ds, System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior runBehavior, string resetOptionsString, bool isInternal, bool forDescribeParameterEncryption, bool shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)    Unknown
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(System.Data.CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior runBehavior, bool returnStream, bool async, int timeout, out System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, bool asyncWrite, bool inRetry, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader ds, bool describeParameterEncryptionRequest)  Unknown
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior runBehavior, bool returnStream, string method, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<object> completion, int timeout, out System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, out bool usedCache, bool asyncWrite, bool inRetry)   Unknown
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior runBehavior, bool returnStream, string method) Unknown
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior, string method) Unknown
>   EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.IDbCommandInterceptor>.Dispatch<System.Data.Common.DbCommand, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader>, System.Data.Common.DbDataReader>(System.Data.Common.DbCommand target, System.Func<System.Data.Common.DbCommand, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader>, System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> operation, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext, System.Action<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.IDbCommandInterceptor, System.Data.Common.DbCommand, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader>> executing, System.Action<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.IDbCommandInterceptor, System.Data.Common.DbCommand, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader>> executed) Line 138  C#
    EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) Line 103   C#
    EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, object> identifierValues, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.PropagatorResult, object>> generatedValues) Line 118  C#
    EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() Line 532  C#
    EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction<int>(System.Func<int> func, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, bool startLocalTransaction, bool releaseConnectionOnSuccess) Line 2203 C#
    EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.SaveOptions options, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, bool startLocalTransaction) Line 2148   C#
    EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll!System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute<int>(System.Func<int> operation) Unknown
    EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.SaveOptions options, bool executeInExistingTransaction) Line 2046 C#
    EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() Line 483  C#
    Machshevet.dll!Machshevet.Core.RecordContext.SaveChanges() Line 762 Basic
    Machshevet.dll!Machshevet.Windows.RecordWindow.Save() Line 169  Basic
    Machshevet.dll!Machshevet.Windows.RecordWindow.<closure>.<lambda35-0>() Line 44 Basic
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnExecuted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.ExecuteCommandBinding(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e, System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding commandBinding)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(System.Windows.Input.CommandBindingCollection commandBindings, object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e, System.Windows.Input.ICommand command, bool execute)    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e, System.Windows.Input.ICommand command, bool execute)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnExecuted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised)    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteImpl(object parameter, System.Windows.IInputElement target, bool userInitiated)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.TransferEvent(System.Windows.IInputElement newSource, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnExecuted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised)    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteImpl(object parameter, System.Windows.IInputElement target, bool userInitiated)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(System.Windows.Input.ICommandSource commandSource, bool userInitiated)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()  Unknown
    System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonButton.OnClick()    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised)    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, System.Windows.RoutedEvent newEvent)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised)    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args)    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs input)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport inputReport)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.Windows.Input.InputMode mode, int timestamp, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions actions, int x, int y, int wheel)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown
```

Comment: Is `Sales` a heap by chance?

Comment: 1) What SQL statement are you running from SSMS? 2) If you run the same statement from code, what happens? 3) If you run the SQL statement via a base-class DbContext, what happens?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: I'm not sure what you mean by a heap. Sales is pretty much a standard table in the database. It is the parent table for SaleProducts.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: The SQL statement I posted in quite clearly. I will try to run the statement via SqlClient and report back.

Comment: 1. The SQL statement contains parameters; how are you filling them for SSMS? 2.. I'm guessing [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) is what AlwaysLearning is referring to.

Comment: For anything that takes that long, look for blocking and open transactions in SQL Server.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: Hi. Thanks for chipping in. Both tables have Clustered primary keys. so I guess neither will be considered heaps

Comment: Hi @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, Thanks for your input. `sys.processes` show no open transactions. What else can I check?

Answer (score 1):

The specific answer to this issue will require seeing the specific code responsible. It likely is not an issue with a single table beyond the relationships that table has defined within the DbContext and database schema, and the current state of what the DbContext is tracking. (And what the Database might be locking, though that is usually a more intermittent type of problem)

Some things to check:
In your App example, you appear to be getting a fresh instance of the DbContext and disposing it. (Good) Does the 11s time reflect the Find+Save, or just Save? The very first query that a DbContext executes in an application incurs a 1-off (think Static) spin-up cost to initialize the model.  For a more accurate timing with a first run scenario, you could do something like:

```
Using d = GetSystemContext(True)
    Dim dump = d.Sales.Any()
    ' Start timing here...
    Dim sp = d.Find(Of SaleProduct)(66246)
    sp.DiscountAmount += 1
    d.SaveChanges()
    ' End timing here...
End Using
```

*Sorry, my VB.Net is sadly out of date.. :) In any case, using a quick operation against the DbContext like an `Any()` will incur the 1-off spin-up cost. Any operation after that should be a more pure representation of the time needed to load & save data.

In your problematic code, are DbContext's guaranteed to be short-lived like this?  DbContexts that are alive longer accrue references to a number of entities and any time any entity is persisted, it will scour it's tree of entities to determine if any related ones may need to be updated. Short-lived, disposed DbContexts are the way to go.

Have you run a profiler against the database to capture the exact SQL being run? Your example SQL doesn't look like an EF query, and references a "Sales" table rather than "SalesProduct". Having a profiler running while debugging your EF application operations is invaluable for revealing stuff going on behind the scenes that you don't expect.

Other possibilities would really depend on the code in question, but a profiler combined with breakpoints will generally help spot issues. Is the delay confirmed to be just when DbContext.SaveChanges happens, or the whole save process? If it's something like from the time the user clicks a Save button, then a Profiler might reveal that your code is tripping a lot of lazy-load calls (loading data to check and update prior to saving) or loading unexpected data. (common issues I've seen are misplaced `ToList()` calls before filtering statements, usually because the devs want to do something that EF cannot translate and `ToList()` seems like a "fix") If the delay is just from SaveChanges then the profiler can confirm what Update statements and the like are being produced and how long they are taking to run.

Comment: oh wow @steve-py, thanks for all this info. I will review piece by piece and see what I can find.1st step. the 11 seconds is the save only. The Find maybe is another second or so. The whole function takes maybe 12 seconds. pretty irrelevant. Our real issue is when it takes 5 minutes plus.

Comment: In the problematic code, the context is not considered short lived. the point here is to load an entity, bind it to windows controls, have the user make his necessary changes and save. though for testing I can open the window+edit+press save in about 3 seconds. and the issue will still be persistent.

Comment: Regarding additional entities, I checked the `ChangeTracker`, and there are no extra entities. Just the 2 that need to be there (SaleProduct and its parent Sale). When a user updates a SaleProduct, I set a LastEditedOn=Now on the the Sale itself. Hence EF also updates the Sales table at the same time

Comment: I've posted a trace here https://pastebin.com/enLgE0Ln . I don't see anything major. But I'd love to hear what you see there. Thanks!

Comment: For profiling you can use SSMS Tools\SQL Profiler or an application like Express Profiler. From there set a breakpoint in your application, clear the profile log, then capture what happens during just the save. It helps to do this on a database copy that has nothing else running against it to reduce noise from other copies of the app.   From the trace you provided it looks to have done several reads and 1 update against Sale in the span of ~44 seconds.  I didn't see an update on SaleProduct.

Comment: Hi. I added a new trace here https://paste.ee/p/sIys6 . This was captured from the `SaveChanges` breakpoint till a few minutes. I didn't wait till it completes which would take 5 minutes plus, and blow up the trace file. But I dont see any reference to Sales table. Maybe I missed some important event in the trace? Which events are important for this issue?

Comment: I don't think that trace is going to help much because that looks to be running on a database server that is already doing quite a bit. To track down performance issues you really need to set it up in an isolated environment with nothing else running against the database. From there just a Profiler result (capturing the SQL and the running time) is enough. If on an isolated database with nothing else running you are seeing a delay then it's a matter of looking at the SQL running during the save. If it is faster in isolation then you likely have a lot of blocking from ReadCommitted everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it seems that the error disappeared after a index rebuild. Even though I cant understand if it was an index issue, how come it worked flawlessly time and again via SSMS and EF without window. But for now its working just dandy. Thanks again for all posters, as you were extremely helpful in narrowing down and focusing.

Answer (score -2):

Entity framework is slow , very slow
in production code you need to use c# SQL command